# Storing values to an Array using foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

My code:

```
$videos_key = array();
foreach($result[$x]["videos_key"] as $videoskey => $result[$x]["videos_key"] ) 
    {
        $videos_key[$videoskey] = $result[$x]["videos_key"];
    }


print_r($videos_key);
```

I want to store all values inside `$result[$x]["videos_key"]` to `$videos_key` variable

But i am getting this error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: `$result[$x]["videos_key"]` : is it an array?

Comment: You should first have a look at PHP's documentation: [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: `$result[$x]["videos_key"]` what is `$x` and is this an array

Comment: I am using this code inside an forloop. $x is like 0,1,2,3 @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: @SébastienTemprado Yes, it is an array (working)

Answer (score 2):

That syntax you use is to split your array in key value pairs.

```
$videos_key = array(
   array('id' => 1, 'value' => 'test')
);

$video_keys_out = array();

foreach($videokey as $key => $value) {
    $videos_keys_out[$key] = $value;
}
```

something like that. I don't know the rest of your code. So with that syntax you fetch the id and value keypair form the first array and you can work with them.

Comment: Hey `videokey` is not defined variable. So i am getting 2 errors `Notice: Undefined variable: videokey` 

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`